# tf-idf and LDA on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, scikit-learn, tf-idf, lda, gensim

I have a python code that uses sklearn and gensim libraries for tf-idf and LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation). Now that I want to migrate to Google app engine I can't use any of these two libraries because they are not supported yet. Is there any service already included in Google app engine that I can use instead of these two libraries to do tf-idf and LDA?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using any of GAE-specific tools, try deploying your app on Heroku. It let's you deploy a whole virtual environment with all the installed libraries on it.